# Microsoft OData in .NET CORE 5 - Adding OData to services throws up a missing using directive yet the package is there

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata, microsoft-odata

I am developing in .net core 5.0. ([There is a tutorial by Sam Xu on moving to dotnet core 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/move-odata-to-net-5/))

I have gone back to the absolute bare minimum with the most simple API project in Visual Studio.

I had this working in my project earlier in the year and it was running on .net core 5.0. See tutorial above.

In this project I have created a new project. Then I went to NuGet to get the package "Microsoft.AspNet.OData" version 7.4.1

I then added the following to the startup file.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddOData();  //THIS ONE
}
```

I added "services.AddOData" and its throwing up the error,

> Error CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddOData' and no accessible extension method 'AddOData' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    JobsLedger.API  C:\Users/.../JobsLedger.API\Startup.cs  35  Active

I had already added the package required for this service. Now I had this working a couple of months ago.

Is there a new package that you need to add?

What am I doing wrong or is this a "breaking change" that I dont know about?

Comment: did you add the `using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions;`in your Startup.cs?

Comment: I solved this by going back to a point where my original project actually built and then upgrading the packages again. This time it now builds and yes I note I did have the suggestion already in the using statements as suggested just above.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` instead?
Note: Version 8.0 Preview has some breaking changes

Answer (score 33):

if you are using .net5.0 it required odata 8.0 preview.

In rc2, according to this article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-odata-8-0-rc/, Sam Xu made a breaking change.

"AddOData is changed from extensions on ISerivceCollection to extension on IMvc(Core)Builder.
**The migration is easy by calling AddControllers() first, then calling AddOData().**"

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddOData(opt => opt.AddModel("odata", GetEdmModel()));
```

**[UPDATE - 11/2021]**

In odata 8.0 AddModel doesn't exist anymore, it was renamed with AddRouteComponents

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddOData(opt => opt.AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel()));
```

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/api-versioning-extension-with-asp-net-core-odata-8/

Comment: Nope, it's not on there either.

Comment: @BenRobinson I needed to add a using statement for Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;

Comment: `AddModel` doesn't seem to exist anymore. Looks like we are supposed to use `.AddOData(opt => opt.AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel()));` instead.

Comment: This answer needs to be either fixed or removed. I just wasted 30 minutes trying to get this to work when @JonathanAllen's comment is the actual answer.

Comment: I just added odata 8.0 today in one of our projects and am glad the answer is updated with @JonathanAllen's comments.

Comment: If you're using EF Core, you want v6 as well. EF Core 5 doesn't support the $apply feature.

Answer (score 1):

For .Net 7.0, AddOData works with IMvcBuilder, as shown below

```
services.AddMvc().AddOData();
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.odata.odatamvcbuilderextensions.addodata?view=odata-aspnetcore-8.0

[image]